# cscope basic key behavior - can it be configured? (NOT vim related)

Tags: cscope

I'm using Cscope 15.7a on Mac.

1) To go to a different search field, I have to press return. I could have sworn in the past I didn't get "[A" and "[B" in the output if I used the up/down keys. And maybe TAB also moved between fields.

2) When I get search results, I can't select a result to open by navigating up and down with the cursor and pressing enter. I have to select based on an result number (a-z, 0-9).

I don't recall exactly what the behavior was in the past but I don't remember cscope being so counter-intuitive/unnatural. Is there a way to modify the key actions? (note, this is nothing to do with vim key mappings)

Comment: cscope 15.8a on a different Mac has cursor navigation. But I don't know whether the version is the reason or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in 15.7a. It is fixed:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31835

Currently macports is on 15.8a. So that should work.